# Event on a click everywhere on the page outside of the specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to hide a div when user click anywhere on the page outside of that div. How can I do that using raw javascript or jQuery?

Comment: I think the jQuery focusout()-Event will solve your problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Attach a click event to the document to hide the div:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   $('#somediv').hide();
});
```

Attach a click event to the div to stop clicks on it from propagating to the document:

```
$('#somediv').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: AFAIK, with jQuery in the second event handler you only need to "return false;" to stop the propagation. http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click (near the bottom of the page)

Comment: @scunliffe - That's true, they basically do the same thing. The nice thing about stopProp is that it doesn't have to be the last line, so you can always put it on the first line for readability, for example.

Comment: This solution can cause unexpected behavior from other libraries, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).

Answer (score 2):

First idea, in raw javascript (from [this post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?p=465274&postcount=4)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
      #mydiv{
        background-color: #999999;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
      }
      -->
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.onclick=check;
      function check(e)
      {
        var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
        var obj = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        if(target!=obj){obj.style.display='none'}
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv">my div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tested with IE6 and FireFox3.1, it does work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

It sure sounds like you want a modal dialog. This jQuery plugin http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/ looks like it has potential.

Answer (score 0):

If the div has the focus, you could attach to the onblur event.