# How to detect a click on anything other than this one div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div with the class "myProfile" when the user clicks anywhere outside that div. How can I do this?

I have this so far but obviously it says hide the div when the user clicks on it instead of "outside" it:

```
$('.myProfile').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321239/event-on-a-click-everywhere-on-the-page-outside-of-the-specific-div

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').click(function(event){

  if (!$(event.target).hasClass('myProfile'))
  {
    $(event.target).hide();
  }

});
```

Comment: Of course, this way any a click on another element that has a click event will just trigger its own click event and won't trigger the body click event.

Comment: @dsclementsen not unless the event handler stops the propagation.

Comment: @Pablo: I don't know how to vote to close, but I followed your advice and posted a comment on the question. I also deleted my own answer. Just trying to be a good citizen.

Comment: Pablo is right, any other click handlers will need `event.stopPropagation();` otherwise they will also try to hide myProfile as well as execute whatever they're meant to.

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez, @Archonix, you are right, I stand corrected. Still it's something to keep in mind. The invisible parent div that covers the whole screen method that @Michael suggested is also a decent approach if that could be an issue (not sure why he got downvoted).

Comment: @Klinger sorry, my bad. Closing option appears only if your rep >= 3k

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could create another div beneath `.myProfile` that takes up all the space on your page. To the click event of this div you hide both this special layer and your profile view/box. This is a very common way to implement the modal box. This way you don't have to listen on all other elements.

I believe that this is also the way it is done by the popular [Lightbox 2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) and definitely used in my own very unpopular code hehe.