# How to make a click on a child element not be considered a click on it's parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question of how to detect a click on anywhere except a specified element has been answered a couple of items like here:

[Event on a click everywhere on the page outside of the specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321239/event-on-a-click-everywhere-on-the-page-outside-of-the-specific-div)

The problem I have is trying to figure out how to detect a click anywhere except a given element including one of it's children.

For example in this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5cEm/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$(document).click(function(e) {
   $('#somediv').hide();
});
$('#somediv').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

});
</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid red; width:100px; height: 100px" id="somediv">

    <span style="display: block; border: 1px solid green; width:50px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto" id="someSpan"></span>

</div>
```

Clicking anywhere outside the red div should cause it to hide. Not only that but also clicking on it's child element (the green span) should cause it to hide. The only time it shouldn't hide is if you click on it but not on the span. As it stands now, the click on the span is also considered a click on the parent div hence it doesn't hide the div if the span is clicked.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare the click's target to the element in question:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != $('#somediv')[0]) {
        $('#somediv').hide();
    }
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K5cEm/7/**

Comment: You do understand that `$(e.target).get(0)` is the same as `e.target`, right? `:)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was a jQuery object.

Comment: In this particular case, the check can be: `if ( e.target.id !== 'somediv' ) { ...`

Comment: Thanks for the second optimization. I'll keep it general for now, but the OP can optimize it if he/she wishes.

Comment: As some bonus information, you can use if($("#parentDiv").has(e.target).length) to check if the child element is contained at all within a div. This is especially useful for bootstrap buttons where you could actually be clicking on the <i> or the <button> elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$('#somediv').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}).children().click(function(e) {
    $('#somediv').hide();
});
```

Here's your updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5cEm/5/

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like so:

```
$(function () {
    var elem = $( '#somediv' )[0];

    $( document ).click( function ( e ) {
        if ( e.target !== elem ) {
            $( elem ).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uMLrC/

So this

```
var elem = $( '#somediv' )[0];
```

caches the reference to the DIV element. We want to cache this reference on page load, so that we don't have to query for that element repeatedly. And it improves the readability of the code, also.